# SFML drawing, square appears when changing the png file with paint

Tags: image, transparency, sfml

I am newbie in SFML C++, i have a problem:
When i am programing on "Doodle game", with the original image of "Doodle", it works correctly.

[image: Using original Doodle 's image]

But when i change the Doodle.png, such as erasing the doodle's head (with paint.exe), the game displays this:

[image: I erased the doodle's head]

A square displays behind the doodle image, as you see! Please, i really want to know what happened with the png file and how can i create the png file like the original one? Do I need an application other than Paint?

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft Paint doesn't properly support alpha transparency in PNG images. As such it will replace the former transparent pixels with pure white.

Use a different editor with proper support for alpha channels, such as [Paint.NET](http://www.getpaint.net/) (freeware) should solve this problem.